# PHP & JSON : Multidimensional JSON combine format tweaking

Tags: php, mysql, json

So far my JSON output is like this

```
[{"dateClose":"2012-07-06","countno":"6","cumulative_sumc":"103"}],[{"dateOpen":"2012-05-29","openNo":"73","cumulative_sum":"73"}]
```

Where in fact I'd like to have it like the below, just in one multidimensional array

```
[{"dateClose":"2012-07-06","countno":"6","cumulative_sumc":"103","dateOpen":"2012-05-29","openNo":"73","cumulative_sum":"73"}]
```

I've been using array_merge,array_combine against project1[] and project[] array, but no luck. My sample code is below. Any helps will be very much appreciated.Thanks.

```
   <?php
require_once('mysql.inc.php');
$dbc =@mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
$x="Set @csum := 0";
$q = "
select dateClose, countno, (@csum := @csum + countno) as cumulative_sumc
from dateclose
order by dateClose";
$rx = mysqli_query($dbc, $x);
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
if (mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$project[] = $row;
}}
$y="Set @csum := 0";
$z = "
select dateOpen, openNo, (@csum := @csum + openNo) as cumulative_sum
from dateopen
order by dateOpen";
$rx = mysqli_query($dbc, $y);
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $z);
if (mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
array_push($project, $row);
}}


echo json_encode($project);


?>
```

Comment: Your 1st JSON isn't valid JSON, and your 2nd isn't a multidimensional array.

Comment: Thanks , I've tried to check using jsonlint.com ..It looks like a a valid json for both ..hmmm..anyway is there a best way to get those expected format?

Answer (score 1):

Try `$project[] = $row;` instead of `$project1[] = $row;` in your script to achieve your JSON output.

Comment: there is an improvement where the [] symbol get removed ,but the json data appears on separate {} ,if possible would like something like below where it's embedded in {}                      [{"dateClose":"2012-07-06","countno":"6","cumulative_sumc":"103","dateOpen":"2012-05-29","openNo":"73","cumulative_sum":"73"}]

Comment: Ohh. you should have said before. Anyway, try this: Instead of again `$project1[] = $row` (in the second while), use this `array_push($project, $row);`. This should help!

Comment: can you post your complete code again to debug? Maybe update the post with latest code?

Comment: don't worry we're going to crack it. I've edited the code please use that one and try: http://pastebin.com/a50SjzP9

Comment: looks better with this output  "[2012-05-31","1","1","2012-06-06","13","14","2012-06-07","31","45"] -the only remaining is to have those key value as well inside it i.e dateClose":"2012-05-31","countno":"1","cumulative_sumc":"1"...

Comment: Oops, my badness! I forgot you also want to preserve keys.. Okay, here is the final revision: http://pastebin.com/imtS8LXA

Comment: Opps...got the keys but it only print the last array  -instead of iterate each and single array and print it out {"dateClose":"2012-07-06","countno":"6","cumulative_sumc":"103","dateOpen":"2012-07-05","openNo":"1","cumulative_sum":"145"}

Comment: what field is similar between these two tables, dateopen and dateclose?

Comment: there is no similarity between tables actually ..dataopen and dateclose 's dataype are date but having different value

Comment: then how could you decide which record of table dataopen corresponds to which record of dataclose? even loops are different. there must be something common for both, if not, the database design is poor.

Comment: the json data needed for line chart .Hence you will have  2 values and lines in the chart  for date open and date close .Those record actually comes from the exposed mysql view/stored procedure.